# Addressing spatially nested data in nMDS?

Tags: mixed-model, pca

I have an experiment comparing bird community composition in different forest stands, having subsampled each stand a few times.  Is there any way to account for this subsampling (i.e., non-independent points) within stands in nMDS?  I know I could use a stand grouping variable as a random effect in GLMs but am unaware of any equivalent for ordinations.

Comment: nMDS isn't (typically) a constrained form of ordination. If you use a constrained ordination method you can either account for the *stand* effect by adding fixed effects for `stand` to the model (perhaps partialling the forest stand effect out of the model before estimating the effects of other covariates. Or you could estimate the effects of other covariates and then use restricted permutations (at the *stand* level) to condition the permutation tests to not swap observations from one stand with another.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  I could do a partial CCA using the stand as a condition.  However, this is not something I'm familiar with.  Are there any assumptions/data requirements for that sort of analysis that I should be aware of.

Comment: The main assumption is that conditional upon the model, the residuals of the fit are exchangeable. We assume this because the permutation test in the model-based approach (where you partial out or otherwise account for the nesting structure via terms in the model) assumes that we can randomly permute residuals, i.e. exchange one residual with any other regardless of *stand*. That can only be true if you have accounted for those effects in the model.

Comment: If you went design-based, there are ways to permute the data only within *stands* say to achieve a similar result/effect, but that requires restricted permutations.